# find world-writable files with powershell

Tags: powershell

I can use this command on my Win10 machine to discover files that are writable by everyone (within the current dir hierarchy):

```
get-childitem -recurse | get-acl | out-string -stream | select-string -pattern "everyone"
```

That works fine but on my Win7 machine the `out-string -stream` seems to truncate the output the `select-string` fails.

Is there a way to find the files on Win7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the appropriate properties instead of converting the `Get-Acl` output to a string. This works on all Windows versions:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName
    $acl.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone' }
}
```

You can expand the check to actually detect ACEs that allow write access to "Everyone" (the above would detect *any* ACE for "Everyone"):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName
    $acl.Access | Where-Object {
        $_.IdentityReference -eq 'Everyone' -and
        $_.AccessControlType -eq 'Allow' -and
        $_.FileSystemRights -band 278
    }
}
```

Beware, though, that DENY ACLs take precedence over ALLOW ACLs, and explicit ACLs take precedence over inherited ACLs, so "Everyone" may or may not actually have write access even if there is an ACE granting write access.

- ALLOW ACE without DENY ACE ⇒ access allowed (obviously)
- DENY ACE without ALLOW ACE ⇒ access denied (obviously)
- inherited ALLOW ACE and inherited DENY ACE ⇒ access denied
- explicit ALLOW ACE and inherited DENY ACE ⇒ access allowed
- inherited ALLOW ACE and explicit DENY ACE ⇒ access denied
- explicit ALLOW ACE and explicit DENY ACE ⇒ access denied

Comment: wish I could add both as answers, but this one is so full-featured. Thanks for the tip about deny overriding allow. At least this will get me a list for further, manual inspection.

Comment: Great info. Is there a high-level method for determining the _effective_ access rights for a given trustee (user) based on applying the precedence rules you mention, short of trying to call the WinAPI's [`GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Aclapi/nf-aclapi-geteffectiverightsfromacla) function?

Comment: @mklement0 I feel like there *should* be one, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @mklement0 There appears to be a PowerShell module ([`PowerShellAccessControl`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShellAccessControl-d3be7b83)) that allows resolving the effective permissions of an item. But since it seems to be using P/Invoke I'd suspect that there is no .Net API for this.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Get-Acl | 
        Where-Object { $_.AccessToString -match 'everyone' } | 
            Select-Object Path, Owner, @{Name='Access'; Expression={$_.AccessToString}} | 
                Format-List
```

(you can write this as a one-liner, but for the sake of readability..)